# Npm Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm

I'am trying to run npm i command on my project but its showing an error can't find python executable python. you can set python env variable. Please any one help me on this. Great thanks in advance.

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:282:31
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\node\\node.exe" "C:\\node\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\vks\\prok\\vk\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v64-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\vks\\prok\\vk\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v64-win32-x64" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v64"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\vk\prok\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\node\node.exe C:\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\vks\prok\vk\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v64-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\vks\prok\vk\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v64-win32-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vks\prok\vk\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\node\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\vks\\prok\\vk\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\vks\prok\vk\node_modules\sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\node\node.exe C:\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\vks\prok\vk\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v64-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\vks\prok\vk\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v64-win32-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
npm WARN ajv-keywords@2.1.1 requires a peer of ajv@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eic_api@1.11.0-0 No repository field.
npm WARN eic_api@1.11.0-0 No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@4.1.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@4.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vk\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-16T05_11_44_737Z-debug.log
```

Right now im getting this error on my system

```
1304 warn ajv-keywords@2.1.1 requires a peer of ajv@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
1305 warn eic_api@1.13.0 No repository field.
1306 warn eic_api@1.13.0 No license field.
1307 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
1308 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
1309 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
1309 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
1309 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
1309 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
1310 verbose stack Error: sqlite3@4.1.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
1310 verbose stack Exit status 1
1310 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
1310 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:159:13)
1310 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
1310 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
1310 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
1310 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
1311 verbose pkgid sqlite3@4.1.0
1312 verbose cwd C:\Users\test\
1313 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
1314 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--verbose"
1315 verbose node v9.3.0
1316 verbose npm  v6.11.3
1317 error code ELIFECYCLE
1318 error errno 1
1319 error sqlite3@4.1.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
1319 error Exit status 1
1320 error Failed at the sqlite3@4.1.0 install script.
1320 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
1321 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have node version 9.3.0 and npm version 6.11.3 on my system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please set Python path in windows :

---For Windows 10/8/7:

- Open System Properties (Right click Computer in the start menu, or use the keyboard shortcut Win+Pause)
- Click Advanced system settings in the sidebar.
- Click Environment Variables...
- Select PATH in the System variables section
- Click Edit
- Add Python's path to the end of the list (the paths are separated by semicolons). For 
  example:

C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Python27

Comment: Hi @Shantanu Sharma, I have download python from offical website for windows zip file and now I need to set path of python till C:\python\python-3.7.4 or C:\python\python-3.7.4\python.exe ?

Comment: use this : C:\python\python-3.7.4

Comment: Showing Command failed for npm i    configure error
   Error: Command failed: C:\python\python-3.7.4\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];

Comment: gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\python\python-3.7.4\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];                              
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063

Comment: install this  : 
npm install --ignore-scripts

Comment: You said system variables right but i have added on user variables bcoz i don't have access to change system variables.I think it need to be change by root administrative on my system ?

Comment: install this : npm install --ignore-scripts AND 

execute node program with "SUDO" example : sudo node server.js

Comment: No now its saying [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...  for node server.js

Comment: don't use nodemon execute this as simple and core way  ... sudo node server.js

Comment: If i try to start server using node command like node index.js then its automatically stopping after executing few commands i mean not showing that server is start on some port

Comment: kill the process who belongs with this used port.... 
 • Search port :                       lsof -i:4200
 • Kill pid:                                sudo kill 10960

Comment: Iam using windows system @Shantanu so can i use same commands on windows also

Comment: I used this command to find out [   netstat -ano | findStr "8000"  ] but its showing none for it

Comment: Yes killed all node server executions from task manager using ctrl+shift+Esc but still same stopping from execution

Comment: error Error: Command failed: C:\python\python-3.7.4\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info

Comment: I researching so after all, You need Python 2.x. ,

 Using 3.x is not supported.
(1)  first please remove current path of python 3.7
 (2) install python2.x.x set the path of python new python2.x.x

Comment: Let me try it @Shantanu

Comment: There are lot of folders and files are there in 2.7.16 python version. Downloaded tar.xz file from python website so till which file I need to give path

Comment: use this link for window 64 bit : https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.16/python-2.7.16.amd64.msi  

And use python executable EXE

Comment: I think almost done but one final error I got for python that is Error : unable to get local issuer certificate for npm I command

Comment: Stack Error :  sqlite3@4.1.0 install : 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'

Comment: please can you help to solve this i have updated my question with latest error log which i got after python installed.

Comment: I have npm version 6.11.3 so I need to upgrade npm to more.yes I did but still getting same version for node 9.3. Or I need to upgrade node version ?

Comment: I think could you install sqlite : 
npm install sqlite3

Comment: I think the problem is with .npmrc file under project. What this file does. When I run npm I sqlite3 it's shown one ipnumber with port with registry which is available on .npmrc file same one

Comment: Thank you sooo much @Shantanu your great at last it works

Comment: Shantanu, could you clean up these comments and add them into your answer? Comments are subject to deletion, if someone has the same problem they might not see the resolution, and I think you'd rather see upvotes on your answer instead of the comments anyways. Then you can flag the comments as no longer needed and we'll clean them up.

Answer (score 2):

In My case, the issue was because of the Python version.
I was having Python39 but the dependencies which I was trying to install require Python27. When I installed Python27 the issue got resolved automatically.